# ACF if have_rows( ) not returning anything

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm trying to use a repeater field and can't seem to get it to work. I think it's an issue with my if statement because if I remove the while loop and try echo out anything from `<?php if( have_rows($aboutInfo['cards']): ?>` I get nothing. I've tried without the ID, and a hardcoded ID as the 2nd param. Also, just to test I did `<?php if( !have_rows($aboutInfo['cards']): ?>` and was able to get something to echo out.

The print_r above the if statement displays the array.

```
<?
 /*
 Template Name: 01-Homepage
 */
 get_header(); ?>
 <? $aboutInfo = get_field( 'about' ) ?>
 <?$postid = get_the_ID(); ?>
 <div class="row">
   <div class="columns small-12 medium-7">
     <h2>
       <?= $aboutInfo['title'] ?>
     </h2>
     <p class="lead"> <?= $aboutInfo['content'] ?></p>
     <pre><?php print_r($aboutInfo['cards']) ?></pre>
     <?php if( have_rows($aboutInfo['cards'], $postid) ): ?>
       <?php while(have_rows($aboutInfo['cards'])) : the_row(); ?>
       <?php $image = get_sub_field('image') ?>
       <p><?= $image['url'] ?></p>
       <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
 </div>
 <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is what my ACF looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it wrong. There are so many bugs in your code. check
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/ and [have_rows()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/have_rows/) the first param need to be selector. check below code.

```
<?php 

/* Template Name: 01-Homepage */

get_header(); 

$aboutInfo = get_field( 'about' );
$postid    = get_the_ID();

if( have_rows('about') ): 

    $title   = get_sub_field('title');
    $content = get_sub_field('content');

    ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="columns small-12 medium-7">

            <?php while( have_rows( 'about' ) ): the_row(); ?>

                <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                <p class="lead"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
                
                <?php if( have_rows( 'cards' ) ): while( have_rows( 'cards' ) ) : the_row(); ?>

                        <?php $image = get_sub_field( 'image' ); ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />

                <?php endwhile; endif;

            endwhile; ?>    

        </div>

    </div>

<?php endif;

get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: So, It's still not working for me., but If I understand your comment correctly, I can’t pass a variable to the the have_rows function? Is that right? I've added a screenshot above to show how my ACF is setup.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The issues was that I created a group called "about" and the "cards" were nested in that group and to access that field I needed to use "about_cards".

```
<?
 /*
 Template Name: 01-Homepage
 */
 get_header(); ?>
​
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
​
    // group field
    $about = get_field( 'about' ); 
    
    if ( !empty( $about ) ) { ?>
​
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns small-12 medium-7">
​
            <?php if ( !empty( $about['title'] ) ) { ?>
                <h2><?php echo esc_html( $about['title'] ); ?></h2>
            <?php }
            
            if ( !empty( $about['content'] ) ) { ?>
                <p class="lead"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $about['content'] ); ?></p>
            <?php }
​
            if( have_rows( 'about_cards' ) ) : // repeater
​
                while ( have_rows( 'about_cards' ) ) : the_row(); 
​
                    $about_card_image   = get_sub_field('image');
                    $about_card_title   = get_sub_field('title');
                    $about_card_content = get_sub_field('content');
​
                    if ( !empty( $about_card_image ) ) {
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $about_card_image, 'medium' );
                    }
​
                    if ( !empty( $about_card_title ) ) {
                        echo '<h3>' . esc_html( $about_card_title ) . '</h3>';
                    }
​
                    if ( !empty( $about_card_content ) ) {
                        echo '<p>' . esc_html( $about_card_content ) . '</p>';
                    } ?>
​
                <?php endwhile;
            endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
​
    <?php } // about field not empty ?>
​
<?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>
​
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

/* Template Name: 01-Homepage */

get_header(); 

$aboutInfo = get_field( 'about' );
$postid    = get_the_ID();

if( have_rows('about') ): 

    $title   = get_sub_field('title',$postid);
    $content = get_sub_field('content',$postid);

    ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="columns small-12 medium-7">

            <?php while( have_rows( 'about',$postid) ): the_row(); ?>

                <h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
                <p class="lead"><?php echo $content; ?></p>
                
                <?php if( have_rows( 'cards' ) ): while( have_rows( 'cards',$postid ) ) : the_row(); ?>

                        <?php $image = get_sub_field( 'image' ); ?>

                        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />

                <?php endwhile; endif;

            endwhile; ?>    

        </div>

    </div>

<?php endif;

get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: the code defines a PHP template named "01-Homepage" for the WordPress admin panel. It retrieves data from the 'about' field, including 'title', 'content', and 'image', and displays them on the homepage. The header and footer template files are included. The code ensures that the 'about' field has rows of data before displaying the content. Overall, it creates a dynamic homepage layout with the retrieved information.